# Is there a way to do "parameter pattern matching" in Julia via the Typesystem?

Tags: types, parameters, julia

Imagine a file reader or similar with states as symbols (`:read`, `:write`, ...) instead of the current string approach.

```
open(file, :read)
```

To my understanding a declaration of `open` would have to contain a match/case (if chain) for the state (in this case symbol)
A possible workaround would be to use a parameterized struct since symbols and really anything is a type

```
struct open{T}
    open{:read}(path::String) = ...
    open{:write}(path::String) = ...
end
```

My current approach to avoiding parameterized structs (for performance and complexity reasons) is to directly pass a type as parameter. Like in this big endian conversion.

```
function get_bigendian(T::Type{<:Unsigned}, data::Vector{UInt8})::T
    @inbounds reinterpret(T, reverse(data))[1]
end
```

But could the state-symbol example from earlier be replicated in the same manner?

```
open(path::String, ::Type{:read}) = ...
```

This compiles just fine, but I can find no way to actually pass this "type". `open(path, :read)` interprets `:read` as a symbol and `Type{:read}` is reasonably understood as
a `Type{Type{:read}}`. Solving this would probably be expandable to not just symbols but Integers and constants in general.

Can something like this be achieved in Julia? Am I missing something?

I guess I'm essentially trying to replicate the Haskell way (eg `factorial 0 = 1`)

#### tl;dr: Can function parameters be constants like `::Type{2}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use types `Val{:symbol}` or `Val{1}`, `Val{2}`,  etc.
To pass this as arguments it can be constructed as `Val{:symbol}()` or `Val{1}()`.

This makes it even possible to move computations to compile time instead of the runtime.

Consider this code:

```
fact(::Val{0}) = 1;

fact(::Val{N}) where N = N*fact(Val{N-1}())
```

Now you can do:

```
julia> fact(Val{5}())
120
```

But the interesting part is how it got compiled:

```
julia> @code_llvm(fact(Val{5}()))
;  @ REPL[23]:1 within `fact`
; Function Attrs: uwtable
define i64 @julia_fact_192() #0 {
top:
  ret i64 120
}
```

Comment: Am I correct, that this also utilizes the struct workaround because types can be constants as type parameters? (Well that might just extend to `Type{N}` in general)